# Multiple bib-files for multiple bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, jurabib

I would like to use multiple bib-files for multiple bibliographies in my seminar work (I want to split books from internet sources). To simplify it, I tried to create 2 bib-files and then do
`\section{Books}
\bibliography{sourcesbooks}
\section{Internet sources}
\bibliography{sources2}`.
But this just prints the same bibliography 2 times. I also tried some packages, like `multibib`, `bibtopic`, etc. (I am using `jurabib` for footcites and so on).

Comment: With `biblatex` it is very easy to filter bibliographies based on categories. For example `\printbibliography[type=article]
`

Comment: Second the vote for `biblatex` for customizatio and advanced stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please in the future post a compilable minimal example from which to start helping you to get what you want.

However, as samcarter already said: It will be a very good idea for you to switch to BibLaTeX, where all of this will be very easy. There, you can add as many bib-files as you want, using several `\addbibresource{}` commands. You can then simply print separate bibliographies per entry-type using

```
\printbibliography[title=Articles, type=article]
\printbibliography[title=Books, type=book]
```

Or you can apply even finer separation of entry-types, by first defining separate bibfilters and using the subtype-field per entry, eg.

```
\defbibfilter{BookType1}{type=book and subtype=Type1}
\defbibfilter{BookType2}{type=book and subtype=Type2}
\printbibliography[title=Books of Type 1, filter=BookType1]
\printbibliography[title=Books of Type 2, filter=BookType2]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to edit MUCH things, but this solution seems to work the best. Thank you very much!

Comment: What if the most logical way to disambiguate the sections/entries is by files, not by type? For example, I have "article" type entries in both reviewed.bib and preprint.bib, but I'd like them to be listed in different sections on my CV.

Comment: @DanielKessler Short answer: I don't know, it's probably possible. If you want to do that, you should ask a new question yourself, though. The comments below answers are not the right place to ask for something basically completely different to achieve.